# MATLAB Simscape: modeling variable load with varying DC voltage

Tags: power-supply, simulation, solar-cell, matlab, simulink

I have a model for a solar array and a battery in MATLAB Simulink (simscape). and I would like to model a load given the power consumption over time. The load is connected to the battery the voltage of which varies due to charge and discharge. How can I do that?

Comment: Search for the keyword [active load](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?q=Active+load). Basically, use a transistor to draw a desired amount of current from the power supply. It will draw a proportional amount of power from the supply when supply voltage is regulated.

Comment: Instead of a circuit, you can also use an ideal current source (in this case, acting as a current sink) of the appropriate polarity instead of a load resistor if simscape has current sources.

Answer (score 1):

If the battery voltage is v(t) and the instantaneous power consumption is p(t), then the current drawn must be p/v.

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't work for some reason.